# How to subdivide road polygons into equal distance polygons while also vertically splitting depending on the width of the road

Tags: qgis, polygon, splitting

I'm using QGIS and trying to divide a road polygons layer into smaller polygons, all having the more or less the same length as in the image below I roughly drew. Also, if the road width is above a certain limit I'd like to divide them from centreline as well. I was wondering if there is a way of doing this automatically. I know that this is a quite difficult problem to solve only with GIS tools but I wanted to ask to wider community as there is always a brighter idea out there.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps if you explained the underlying problem you are trying to address someone might have a different solution that fills your needs.

Comment: +1 good question with possible generic solutions. Perhaps post 2, one for arcmap and one for qgis.

Answer (score 3):

This is a rather broad question therefore I give here only the seeds to answer it.

The first step should be the creation of a skeleton, i.e. the line that goes in the middle of your line. There are some answers to this question (QGIS/PostGIS/SAGA GIS) [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171145/skeletonize-vectors-in-qgis-python) and as you tagged ArcGIS also, you can look for the "Collapse Dual Lines To Centerline" tool.

The second step consists in creating [lines perpendicular to your skeleton](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20855/creating-perpendicular-transects-to-stream-at-specified-intervals-using-arcmap). Again there are several ways to do it. e.g. In PostGIS you could use [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33478/offseting-point-perpendicular-to-line-direction-in-postgis) with [ST_MakeLine](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html)

In the last step you can use the lines that you produced to build your polygons. Draw a negative buffer on your polygons to remove the skeleton when the road isn't large enough.